# HTML design nearby div

Tags: html, css

i want to design below screenShot with html and css. my code have problem and i cant move div like with screenShot.

[image]

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .box1{
                border:1px solid;
                width:200px;
                height:100px;
                float:right;
            }
            .box2{
                border:1px solid;
                width:200px;
                height:100px;
                float:right;
                clear: right;
            }
            .box3{
                border:1px solid;
                width:200px;
                height:100px;
                float:right;
                clear:none;
            }
            .box4{
                border:1px solid;
                width:200px;
                height:100px;
                float:right;
            }
            .box5{
                border:1px solid;
                width:200px;
                height:100px;
                float:right;
                clear: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='box1'></div>
        <div class='box2'></div>
        <div class='box3'></div>
        <div class='box4'></div>
        <div class='box5'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iyOnAPEw/1/ Pasted your code on jsbin so people can see what it does now more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe you can divide your layout into 3 columns

CSS

```
.column{float:left}
.column-middle{float:left;margin:0 5px}
.box-sml{float:left;width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid;margin-bottom:5px}
.box-sml-bottom{float:left;width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid;clear:left}
.box-lrg{float:left;width:200px;height:207px;border:1px solid}
```

HTML

```
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='box-sml'></div>
    <div class='box-sml-bottom'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-middle">
    <div class="box-lrg"></div>
  </div>

  <div class='column'>
    <div class='box-sml'></div>
    <div class='box-sml-bottom'></div>
  </div>
```

http://jsbin.com/UqUNUzUS/2

Answer (score 1):

It is better to structure your website like sidebar-left, center and sidebar-right and inside each of main boxes you can create your smaller boxes.

This way you have a clean css and control over the spaces between boxes.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.box1,.box2,.box3,.box4,.box5{border:1px solid;float:left;}
.box1,.box3{margin-bottom:5px;}
.box1{margin-right:5px;}
.box3,.box4{margin-left:5px;}
.box1,.box3,.box4,.box5 {    
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;    
}
.box2{
    width:200px;
    height:207px;
    float:left;
}
.box5{margin-top:-102px;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HMf78/)

Answer (score -1):

You could use an approach that utilizes the `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` style attributes and it would render just like a `<table>`, [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DEH8B/)